# Block access to rocket.chat via http port in reverse proxy mode

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, rocket.chat

I have installed `rocket.chat` version `0.72.3` on `CentOS 7.6` as a private local team chat.

Then for configuring a reverse proxy to force `rocket.chat` use SSL protocol I installed `nginx` version `1.12.2` and followed this link `https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/mobile-apps/supporting-ssl/` to configure `nginx` as a reverse proxy.

After the configuration was successful, I have two `url`s both pointing to my `rocket.chat` application (`http://localhost:3000` and `https://localhost:443`). I mean `rocket.chat` is accessible under both of these two links which the `http` access is redundant.

How can I disable access to `rocket.chat` via `http://localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 1) bind rocketchat service only to localhost interface and 2) let nginx to listen on public interface and to act as proxy (what you probably already did).

So, first open your `rocketchat.service` file (possibly in `/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat.service`, but this depends on how you did configure rocketchat service) and in `[Service]` section add this line:

```
[Service]
Environment=BIND_IP=127.0.0.1
```

Don't worry that you already have one (or some) `Environment` entries, these are aggregated (as for me I have single `Environement` entry for each variable).

Then open your nginx config (possibly `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, but this may differ) and make sure, that `server` block listens only on port 443 and does its proxy job. My nginx relevant entries look like this:

```
# Upstreams
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/rocketchat.access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

You probably need to reload/restart nginx and rocketchat services and reload config issuing

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

command.

For me it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by blocking external connections to `localhost` and allowing internal connections to `localhost` using `iptables`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```

But I'm still wondering isn't there any config related to `nginx` to sort the issue out?